# Solr performance improvement with disjunctive queries

Tags: performance, search, solr, lucene

I have a solr set up (solr 4.6 on Windows7 with 8 GB RAM and 8 cores) with about 10 million documents and total index size about 7 GB. Queries that I am performing are purely disjunctive with term boosting.
e.g. query:

("stack"^3 "java"2 "j2ee"^4 "programming practises"^........)

I have about 50 terms in a single query.
Performance currently is very bad, each query is taking about 11-12 seconds. Of course if I issue the same query second time I get the result very fast (< 10 ms). However in my case, change of same query happening again are very low. Is there any way I can optimize so that new queries take much less time ?

Comment: How high is the chance that sub-queries occurs again?

Comment: Well it can happen and I agree that caching might help there. But I was generally wondering if I can improve this performance of first time queries in any ways (10-11 seconds for just 50 terms in OR condition seems to be quite bad) ?

Comment: Would you give us a query that is slow 1:1 as you send it to your solr? as example I am not sure if you really surround simple terms as phrases or not, like `"stack"`.

Comment: yes, is "programming practices" one or two terms for you?

Comment: what are you jvm settings? How much ram is free for the OS to use as caching? Is the 11 secs just QTime or includes getting all data to the client?